# Switching to unsupported locales on android 2.2

Tags: android, locale

I am creating a content based application that supports English and Amharic languages.
Content is loaded from server during the first launch and loaded from the sq-lite. Amharic is however not decoded (text looks like small boxes) on gingerbread android version.  on higher versions of android it works well.

Comment: You may need to find a font that supports that language.  My guess would be that earlier versions of Android did not have characters for Amharic

Comment: @AndrewSchuster I searched for amharic fonts and came across washra fonts and it works pretty well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to find a font that supports that language. My guess would be that earlier versions of Android did not have characters for Amharic.  This would likely be true for any languages aren't supported before Android 4.0